# Run all scripts in a folder in background

Tags: bash, background-process

I want to run all scripts in a directory at the same time.

I know that I can get a list of all the scripts and execute the first one in a directory with `ls ./*.sh`, but I can't seem to get all of them to run.

I also tried brace expansion {./*.sh; } but that also ran only the first script.

After I figure out how to run all of the them I want to run all of them in the background.

I know that I can probably do this with a for loop, but I was hoping there is a simple one liner using globbing or brace expansion that will get the job done simply.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for script in ./*.sh; do "$script" & done
wait
```

Or to limit the number of concurrent invocations, with GNU `xargs`:

```
xargs -n1 -P5 -r0a <(printf '%s\0' ./*.sh) env
```

(beware it assumes script names don't contain `=` characters).

Or with `zsh`:

```
autoload zargs # best in ~/.zshrc
zargs -n1 -P5 ./*.sh -- command
```

(here at most 5 at a time).

Beware that if those scripts produce any output they could end-up being badly interleaved. GNU `parallel` addresses that by storing the output of each command in a separate temporary file and outputting them in order:

```
parallel -j0 exec ::: ./*.sh
```

(`-j0` to run all of them in parallel, remove to limit to the number of CPU cores, or specify the number yourself).

Comment: exec is not needed for GNU Parallel. In theory it could be faster, but I have not been able to measure a significant difference.

Comment: @OleTange, it depends on the shell. Some shells optimise out the fork for the last command by themselves (`bash` only when there's only one command), some don't. The gain of CPU time and other resource incurred by that saved `fork()` will also vary greatly depending on the OS kernel. To limit the overhead, best would be to avoid the shell in the first place :-b

Comment: I know the theory, but can you give an actual reproducible example where the above with give a measurable difference if `exec` is left out?

Comment: @OleTange, compare, after `ulimit -u 300`: `PARALLEL_SHELL=dash parallel -j0  sleep ::: {10..130}` with `PARALLEL_SHELL=dash parallel -j0  exec sleep ::: {10..130}`. Also compare max memory usage (and overall CPU time). (note that some versions of `dash` did optimise the last fork, try with csh or fish if your dash is one of those).

Comment: I will grant you, that if you hit the roof of number of processes allowed on your system, then it is an optimization worth using - primarily because GNU Parallel spends a lot of effort dealing with that. However, without the `ulimit` I still see no difference in CPU time or memory usage. If anything the exec version is actually a bit higher.

Comment: @OleTange, without the `exec`, with shells that don't optimise out the last fork, you have two processes running concurrently instead of one, so it has to use more memory. Maybe you based your test result on getrusage()'s ru_maxrss (`time -f %M`). That's the memory usage of the largest process in the process tree, not the largest usage  of the tree.

Comment: Good: So can we reach this conclusion? exec is useful if: You do not have RAM or processes enough to spawn one extra shell per job. It does not, however, speed up the running. Also it only works if there is a single command to be run - composed commands will not run with exec.

Comment: Stephane, is there a reason you use`env` in the`xargs` solution here. Never seen it used like this. Does it have any advantages over `sh`?

Comment: @iruvar, `sh` would also work if all those scripts are `sh` scripts meant to be interpreted by that `sh`. By using `env`, we're _executing_ the scripts themselves so the she-bang (`#! /path/to/interpreter`) if any will be honoured. We need `env` because if you don't provide a command, `xargs` calls `echo` instead. A downside of using `env` is that it would not work properly for scripts whose name contains `=`.

Answer (score 2):

you can execute all the scripts in a folder by passing the folder to the `run-parts` command :

```
run-parts /path/to/folder &
```

Comment: Most motd systems use this to run each script in `/etc/update-motd.d/` https://wiki.debian.org/motd

Answer (score 0):

Run every shell script in background.

```
sh -x script1.sh & sh -x script2.sh & sh -x script3.sh &
```

- Run each script in background mode so that next command is run without waiting for current command to complete.
- '&' makes the scripts run in background so that prompt does not wait for it to complete

Answer (score 0):

You can run any executable file in background by adding `&` to the end of the calling. foe example:

```
./executbaleFile [args] &
```

But when you just do that if you close the session or exit the terminal it will send a `SIGHUP` to the process that you are running.

If you want to make the process keep working even if you close the terminal, you have to `nohup` command. for example:

```
nohup ./executbaleFile [args] &
```

this will let the process working even after you close the terminal.

Or use `disown`., it removes the job from the shell's job list, so when terminating the shell it will not send a `SIGHUP` to the process.

Answer (score -1):

Run the scripts in the background :

```
./myscript.sh & ./myscript2.sh & ....
```